# Debugging whilst developing JavaFX mobile application with gluon mobile plugin

Tags: android, debugging, javafx, gluon-mobile

I am new to javaFx and gluon mobile. In android studio there is the option to debug code whilst it is running on the phone and I was wondering if there is a similar feature for working with intelij and the gluon mobile plugin ? Under the gradle tasks there is a Debug task, which when clicked prints "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" to the console and waits. Unfortunately there is not a lot of documentation/examples regarding this that I could find. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Debug task is for desktop only.

It is intended to debug easily on your machine before deploying to mobile, but obviously it will allow tracking down only common issues, and that won't guarantee that the app will work on Android. I.e. using Streams will run on desktop and it will fail on Android.

To debug the app running on Android, the best way is using `adb` from your Android SDK folder, in the `platform-tools` folder.

Connect your app to the USB and run it. On a terminal go to that folder and run:

```
adb logcat -v threadtime
```

and search through all the messages trying to find out those related to the `FXActivity`.

You can add print outs in your code so you can easily track them in the logs.

There are other tools like the Android `monitor` (under Android sdk/tools folder), that will let you add some filters so you can easily go through the app messages.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have enabled the Debugging Mode on your phone.

Then in Eclipse e.g., you can create a Debug Configuration of type Remote Java Application which will be attached to the corresponding socket:

[image]

You can get the port from the devices view:

[image]

Now you have to start your app first, and then start the Debug Configuration